# Flask Error: typeerror run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'host'

Tags: python, frameworks, flask

I built a website on virtualbox with Flask. The website can be opened on localhost, but I cannot open it through Port forwarding, so I changed the code from `manage.run()` to `manage.run(host='0.0.0.0')`.

The problem is that I am receiving this error:

```
typeerror run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'host'.
```

The similar error occurs when change `manage.run()` to `manage.run(debug=True)`. I just followed the Flask documentation.http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application Could anyone let me know why I'm receiving this error?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

"""Manage Script."""

from sys import stderr, exit

from flask.ext.script import Manager, prompt_bool

from szupa import create_app
from szupa.extensions import db
from szupa.account.models import User
from szupa.context import create_category_db


app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)


@manager.command
def initdb():
    """Initialize database."""
    db.create_all()
    create_category_db()


@manager.command
def migrate(created, action="up"):
    module_name = "migrates.migrate%s" % created
    try:
        module = __import__(module_name, fromlist=["migrates"])
    except ImportError:
        print >> stderr, "The migrate script '%s' is not found." % module_name
        exit(-1)
    if prompt_bool("Confirm to execute migrate script '%s'" % module_name):
        try:
            action = getattr(module, action)
        except AttributeError:
            print >> stderr, "The given action '%s' is invalid." % action
            exit(-1)
        action(db)
        print >> stderr, "Finished."


@manager.command
def dropdb():
    """Drop database."""
    if prompt_bool("Confirm to drop all table from database"):
        db.drop_all()


@manager.command
def setadmin(email):
    """Promote a user to administrator."""
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if not user:
        print >> stderr, "The user with email '%s' could not be found." % email
        exit(-1)
    else:
        user.is_admin = True
        db.session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution! You could post an answer explaining how you solved it and link to that page. It would help anyone else who has the same problem and comes across this post. Here's a [working version of the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130218044123/http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/).

Answer (score 2):

As @fangwz0577 said in a comment, they solved the problem using `manager.add_command`. The archived version of their link is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130218044123/http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/).

> Next, create the manage.py file. Use this file to load additional
>   Flask-scripts in the future. Flask-scripts provides a development
>   server and shell:
>
> ```
> from flask.ext.script import Manager, Server
> from tumblelog import app
>
> manager = Manager(app)
>
>  # Turn on debugger by default and reloader 
> manager.add_command("runserver", Server(
>     use_debugger = True,
>     use_reloader = True,
>     host = '0.0.0.0') )
> ```

Comment: I'm not informed about flask, so if someone wants to write a better answer, please do. I'm just posting this to quote the relevant section and use a working link to preserve the information from @fangwz0577's comment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @SuperBiasedMan is the one who worked for me, except that the import `from flask.ext.script import Manager, Server` doesn't work
because it was deprecated (as an issue on flask's github shows: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1135#issuecomment-61860862)

So if you are still struggling, try to use `from flask_script  import Manager, Server` instead.

Also, on Linux the creation of a "bare bones" application is not needed, just create the `__init__.py` file and make the `manage.py` file.